# How should I say it if I want someone to read an article?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I was reading an article and that was about good teaching. So I wanted to say something like,

**1. I wish if I could get my teachers to read that article, that would be worthwhile**

**2. I wish if I could make them read this, that would be worthwhile**

I like to express that I wish to drag my teachers come to this link and read this. So what will be the best way to say this with any grammatical suggestions for correction? First I wanted to say, I wish if I could get them read that post. But I think read can't be an Adjective. 
I am looking for helps form Native speakers. So, this is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the "if" (and I'd also use a hyphen, as there are two clearly separate, yet related statements) (and I'd also add the word "really", for emphasis).

> I wish I could get my teachers to read that article - that would be really worthwhile.

You could also say:

> It would be really worthwhile if I could get my teachers to read that article.

Or:

> It would be really worthwhile if my teachers were to read that article.

Answer (score 2):

There are a myriad of ways you can think of formulating a sentence. But let me make your first sentence grammatical and succinct.

> If only I could get my teachers to read that article; it'd be worthwhile.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are a native speaker in English right?

Comment: @naasif That's not relevant. Nobody on the website certifies themselves as one.

Comment: "If only" and "I wish" are not exactly the same. The general meaning is still conveyed, a desire that the article is read.  But "if only" does not really go along with "worthwhile" here.

Comment: @NoamanAli So, if I say,  I wish if I could get my teachers to read that article, that would be worthwhile. Is there any wrong?

Comment: @NoamanAli Actually I ain't very used to this 'if only' stuff.

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica Like I said, there are a myriad ways of constructing this sentence. I merely made it more succinct. It's grammatical.

Comment: @naasif Yes, that sentence is constructed wrongly. You could write 'I wish I could get my teachers to read that article; it'd [certainly] be worthwhile.' I've redacted 'if,' because the sentence gives rise to ambiguity.

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica 'If only' is adherent only to the first clause of the sentence. '...worthwhile' is the latter clause.

Comment: The semi-colon makes the sentence sound unnatural. (–1)

Comment: @userr2684291 Can you corroborate?

Comment: @NoamanAli You know what, I'm wrong, and thanks for asking. I don't know why it appeared to me that way. Sorry about that.

Comment: @userr2684291: I believe you were completely right when you said in your first comment that the semicolon makes the sentence sound unnatural. Can you explain why you think now that you were mistaken?